# Tracking jQuery Slider Clicks with Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, jquery

I'm trying to find some resources on tracking the 'previous & next' clicks a user makes whilst interacting with a jQuery slider (in this particular example: http://bxslider.com/ ). Whilst I'm comfortable with event tracking, I have no clue where to begin on integrating this (assuming directly in the .js slider file?).

Thanks a ton in advance for any suggestions, links, etc. :)

Cheers

Noel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this  http://davidwalsh.name/ajax-analytics

here is the jquery method

http://think2loud.com/105-use-jquery-with-google-analytics-to-track-clicks-on-outgoing-links-from-your-site/